# Email from any outside domain bounces back with 554 5.7.1 Relay access denied error

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

i have setup postfix 3.6 on my ubuntu 22.04 vps (cyberpanel) with dovecot and roundcube as my webmail. i managed to fix outgoing emails but now, i am getting relay access denied errors. this is my current /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES

myhostname = mail.hostname.com
mydomain = hostname.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.hostname.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.hostname.com/privkey.pem
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_tls_security_level = may
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept

tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
myorigin = $mydomain
relayhost = 
mailbox_size_limit = 1000000000
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions, mua_client_restrictions, mua_helo_restrictions
mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtputf8_enable = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_data_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:/var/log/policyServerSocket
smtpd_policy_service_default_action = DUNNO
```

and this is my /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

i tried setting compatibility_level to 3.6 and got the same results.

however, the weird part is that when testing using compatibility_level=2 , emails from yahoo mail sometimes gets through and sometimes errors with the 554 relay access denied. emails from gmail accounts are always getting the 554 relay access denied error and gets bounced back.

i have setup my spf and dmarc as well.

i hope someone can help me. thank you very much.

Comment: I have removed the line virtual_alias_domains but i am still getting the 554 error on my bounce back mails.

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden [`virtual_alias_domains`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) with an empty value, rendering your [`virtual_alias_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) useless. Removing that line should fix the problem given the MySQL configuration works.

> [`virtual_alias_domains`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) (default: [`$virtual_alias_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps))
>
> Postfix is the final destination for the specified list of virtual alias domains, that is, domains for which all addresses are aliased to addresses in other local or remote domains. The SMTP server validates recipient addresses with [`$virtual_alias_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) and rejects non-existent recipients. See also the [virtual alias domain](https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#virtual_alias_class) class in the [ADDRESS_CLASS_README](https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) file

Comment: *Edit: i got the relay errors again after an hour, what could possibly be causing it? should i also remove the line relayhost since its blank?

Comment: Please read the documentation: [`relayhost`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) defaults to an empty value.

Comment: thanks, i left it blank but until now i am still getting the 554 relay access denied error. im really stumped as to why it would go through sometimes and sometimes it wont. but most of the times it wont.